In a class A amplifier using a (BJT voltage divider bias) with no transformer coupling, how can one calculate the input DC current?
In a class A amplifier (using a BJT voltage divider bias) with no transformer coupling, how can one calculate the input DC current? The current drawn from the supply is ICQ (which flows in the collector (RC) and emitter (RE) resistors) and current that flows in the voltage divider branch resistors (R1) and (R2). If we do not assume that (RC+RE) << (R1+R2), how can we calculate the current flowing in the voltage divider branch? In the image below RC is shown as RL. Assume the blocking capacitor is not there.


Are you looking for a completely general set of equations that only assume that the transistor is in active mode? Or are you looking for rough back-of-envelope results that take very little time and are "good enough for most uses?" Also, as a note, a completely bypassed (Ce) emitter resistor amplifier is "almost useless" for large output signal swings unless there is global NFB in a larger system of which this section is just one part. The gain is too signal-dependent to avoid significant distortion when the output swing is large enough. And what knowledge do you already have and can apply?

You cannot calculate input DC current as there is a DC blocking capacitor $ C_{1}$ just after signal input and before the resistor divider. In the circuit above, input DC current is zero.

Assume it's not there

@user998479 So, the quiescent DC operating point, voltages and currents, then. This means C1 and Ce can be ignored. Pretty easy. What do I have to work with that is in your head about how to proceed?

The input current is Icc which is the current drawn from the supply Vcc. Part of it is Icq (which I know its value) which flows in the the collector and emitter resistor. I need to obtain the current flowing in resistors R1 and R2. I thought about getting the equivalent resistance of  as seen from Vcc but did not know how to proceed. So Vcc/Req=Icc and then subtract Icq

@user998479 If the simple current calculation of Vcc divided by the sum of R1 plus R2 is a lot more than the required base current, then that's all you need to do. The current will be about the same in both. If the base current is a significant percentage, then you need to apply KVL. Do you follow so far?

@user998479 So, for example:
$$\begin{align*}
V_{\text{TH}}&=V{\text{CC}}\cdot\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}&R{\text{TH}}&=\frac{R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\\V{\text{TH}}-I{\text{B}} \cdot R{\text{TH}}-V{\text{BE}}-\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot I{\text{B}}\cdot R{\text{E}}&=0:\text{V}\\\therefore\\I{\text{B}}&=\frac{V{\text{TH}}-V{\text{BE}}}{R{\text{TH}}+\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R{\text{E}}}
\end{align*}$$Assuming you can specify $V{_\text{BE}}$, a priori. The collector current impacts this. You may need to adjust based on the saturation current and temperature..

@user998479 So you really do need to talk a little more about how much precision you want. And if you want to include temperature in your calculations. Or saturation current. Etc. Details matter.

***If we do not assume that (RC+RE) << (R1+R2), how can we calculate the current flowing in the voltage divider branch? ***  Well, the assumption is that  (R1 + R2) is *not very much greater than (RC+RE) implies that base current is negligible compared to the current in (R1 + R2).   In which case, the current in the "the voltage divider branch", ie: the string formed by R1 & R2 is simply: Vcc / (R1 + R2).

That makes sense @fabiobarone thank you

@FabioBarone; Looks like an answer. You should post as such:)

@user998479 Please provide a link for the screenshot.

Voting to close; the question seems answerable as shown, if a bit strangely worded -- but the comment "assume [C1]'s not there" sounds REALLY strange to me; so, I'm voting for more clarity.  Please edit to include all relevant information, including what to do with C1, the DC voltage at the input and/or output as applicable (e.g. a Thevenin equivalent), and their values.

From the question:

If we do not assume that (RC+RE) << (R1+R2), how can we calculate the
current flowing in the voltage divider branch?

Well, the assumption that (R1 + R2) is NOT very much greater than (RC + RE) implies that the DC bias current in RC (& RE) is perhaps only twice that in R1 (& R2).  If we assume that transistor current gain is, say 200, then that means the current into the transistor base is 1/100 of that flowing in R1 & R2; which is negligible compared to the current in (R1 + R2).
In which case, the current in the "the voltage divider branch", ie: the string formed by R1 & R2, is simply:
i(R1) = i(R2) =  Vcc / (R1 + R2).
If you need to calculate the current in that branch more accurately, simply replace the transistor base connection with a resistor parallel to R2, which has a value 100 times that of R2, so its current is 1/100 that of R2.
If you want to learn more about calculating the DC bias for a BJT, I can recommend this answer:-
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/360635/341959
